# What is the difference between these sentences? 1)Five and five make ten. 2)Five and five is ten

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

1)Five and five make ten.

2)Five and five is ten.

I am wondering why 'Five and five makes ten' is incorrect. Even though I know that 'Five and five make ten' is correct, I am unable to explain the reason to somebody in case I need to do so. Why 'five and five' in the second sentence is treated as singular while 'five and five' in the first is treated as plural?

Comment: Five and five are two items, so they're plural, so you use make. Together, they make ten. 
 
Could *2)* be an ellipsis of *the sum of five and five is ten.*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In math, we speak of *equations* or *equalities*

5 + 5 = 10

The equation, the statement that two expressions yield the same value, can be expressed in natural language in several ways, the first, drawing attention to the equality:

> Five plus five **is** ten.
>
> Five plus five **equals** ten.

the second, drawing attention to the operation of *addition*:

> Five plus five **makes** ten.
>
> Five plus five **adds up to** ten.
>
> Five plus five **gives** ten.

P.S. We can also say

Five plus five **make** ten, or **add up to ten**, or **give** ten.

The decision to use a singular or plural verb hangs on whether the speaker has in mind two distinct elements ("five ... five", understanding **plus** to mean "and") or a single *expression* as the subject, i.e. a singular noun linked by the word **plus** with another noun, as in "five  augmented-by five ...".

These are also valid and grammatical:

> five and five makes ten
>
> five and five make ten
>
> five and five is ten
>
> five and five are ten

depending on the speaker's attitude towards the subject, whether it is compound, consisting of two nouns conjoined, or a single expression.

Comment: This doesn't address the body of the question.  OP wants to understand the distinction between "five and five" as a singular operation (which agrees with "makes" or "is") and as a plural set of operands (which agrees with "make" or "are").  Your explanation employs a noun modified by a prepositional phrase, which doesn't occur anywhere in OP's post.

Comment: Are you considering **plus** a preposition? BTW,  I refer to the whatchamacallit to the left of the verb as an "expression", which does address the OP's question regarding number agreement.

Comment: Yes.  In math it's an operation, but in English grammar it's a preposition.  "Plus" is like "with".  Other such prepositions include "minus" or "less", "times" or "by", and "over".  Since numbers *per se* are singular, "five plus five" does not agree with "are".  "Five and five", on the other hand, is a coordination like "bacon and eggs", sometimes singular, sometimes plural.  Bacon and eggs are ingredients.  Bacon and eggs is my favorite breakfast.

Comment: Plenty of speakers say "5 plus 5 **make** ten" and in doing so they understand **plus** to be an analogue of **and**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two%20plus%20two%20make%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en